# VBA ADO Parametrize LIKE Query

Tags: sql, excel, ado, sql-like, vba

I've looked around but can't seem to find a solution to parametrize a query in VBA using ADO.

I'm looking to achieve something like:

```
.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE F_Name LIKE '%?%'"
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p1", adVarChar, adInputParam, 255, strFname)
```

Could anyone help with how to apply append a parameter in the above manor?

Comment: How about `LIKE '%' & ? & '%'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could append and prepend the % symbol to your string variable before you pass it into CreateParameter

```
.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE F_Name LIKE '?'"
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p1", adVarChar, adInputParam, 255, "%" + strFname + "%")
```

Comment: Doh! That was far too obvious! Thanks @gareththegeek

Answer (score 0):

```
.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE F_Name LIKE ?"
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("p1", adVarChar, adInputParam, 255, "%" + strFname + "%")
```

works for me (without ')